# Dynamic query into a map

Tags: query

In a vf controller, I'm trying to pass a string and a set into a query that goes to a map. I can't seem to get both the set and the string into the same line. Example:

```
private Boolean ValidateContacts(Set<Id> contactIdSet)
{
    String whereText;

    if(
    corpId != null
    )
    whereText = 'Account.Corporate_Account__c = \'' + objOpprtunity.Parent_Account__r.Corporate_Account__c + '\'';
    else {
    whereText = 'AccountId = \'' + objOpprtunity.Parent_Account__c + '\'';
    }

    Map<Id, Contact> inValidContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIdSet AND whereText]);
```

If I do :whereText it errors saying

> Unexpected token ':'

If I do whereText it errors saying

> Unexpected token ']'

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic string in static Querry (Query inside square Bracket)

You have to use Database.query.

```
List<String> contactIdSet = new List<String>{'003123456789632145'};
String whereText = 'AccountId!=null';
String initialQuery ='SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIdSet AND ';
Map<Id, Contact> inValidContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>((List<Contact>)Database.query(initialQuery+whereText));
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic filters means you need to use Database.query. The following should work:

```
Map<Id, Contact> inValidContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>(
  (Contact[])Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIdSet AND ' +whereText
  )
);
```

This presumes that your filters are otherwise correct.